# how to calculate the negation of a selection predicate of a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a sql query '**q**' which is of the form :

```
Select attribute from table1, table2 where  SC;
```

Here '**SC**' is the conjunction of all the selection predicates in **q**

In my case : `SC is balance <1000 and salary >=50000`

Now i want to calculate "**NSC**" which is negation of **SC** in **q** and need some help.

Comment: NSC is balance >=1000 and salary <50000

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. I presume `NOT (balance <1000 and salary >=50000)` isn't what you want? Are you asking how to do `EXCEPT` in MySQL?

Comment: I want balance>= 1000 or salary > 50000. i want to knw how to find the general expression for this or how to calulate it

Comment: If only you'd used proper join syntax

Comment: @Strawberry 1. Irrelevant. See my answer. 2. "," = INNER JOIN with lower precedence. ON = WHERE with higher precedence. INNER JOIN and WHERE both commute, and with each other. ON and INNER JOIN are the wrong solution to the needless awkwardness of SELECT-FROM-WHERE. The correct solution is just normal distinct operators for SELECT, INNER JOIN and WHERE. And "," is just INNER JOIN.

Comment: @philip So there's no other solution than those that you've suggested?

Comment: @Strawberry Is that a non sequitur referring to my answer?

Comment: @user3395103 I have expanded my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per your post you said `i want to calculate "NSC" which is negation of SC` and 
SC is `balance <1000 and salary >=50000`

So, Negation of SC would simply be `balance >= 1000 and salary < 50000`

So, you can do like

```
Select attribute from table1 where balance >= 1000 and salary < 50000
```

(OR)

```
Select attribute from table1 
where attribute not in 
( select attribute from table1 
where balance <1000 and salary >=50000 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your pick of two methods.

**Aside: null**

I will assume there are no NULLs in tables or expressions. Because that complicates things. In particular, if we want to treat NULL as if it were a value in conditions then:

```
v = w   is true in SQL when   v = w AND v IS NOT NULL AND w IS NOT NULL
v != w   is true in SQL when   v != w AND v IS NOT NULL AND
```

Also SQL has lots of special behaviour when there are nulls. Also beware that nulls get generated by SQL in things like OUTER JOIN and IN of a subquery. See [SQL and Relational Theory: How to Write Accurate SQL Code, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022879.do).

**1. not ( expression )**

SQL doesn't have a comparson-negating "not". You can build an expression that is the not of another expression by parsing from the top down:

```
not (c AND d)   is   (not (c) OR not (d))
not (c OR d)   is   (not (c) AND not(d))
not (e NOT NOTable-operator o)   is   (e NOTable-operator o)
not (e NOTable-operator o)   is   (e NOT NOTable-operator o)
not (e NOT NOTable-function(f))   is   (e NOTable-function(f))
not (e notable-function(f))   is   (e NOT NOTable-function(f))
not (e != f)   is   (e = f)
not (e = f)   is   (e != f)
not (v < w)   is   is   (v >= w)
not NOT b   is   b   -- boolean b
not b   is   (NOT (b))   -- boolean b
```

Now given SC you find expression not(SC) and you write:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE not(SC)
```

**2. Not not ( expression )**

In standard SQL you could write the preceding query as:

```
(SELECT ... FROM ...)
EXCEPT
(SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE SC)
```

(In Oracle it's MINUS.) But MySql doesn't have EXCEPT. But `s EXCEPT t` is

```
SELECT s.a,...
FROM s
LEFT JOIN t
ON s.a = t.a AND ...
WHERE t.a IS NULL
```

When s.a has no match in t, t.a IS NULL. So this returns only unmatched rows. So

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE not(SC)
```

is:

```
SELECT s.a,...
FROM (SELECT ... FROM ...) s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE SC) t
ON s.a = t.a AND ...
WHERE t.a IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The general answer to your question is given by [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

```
NOT(P AND Q)  =  NOT(P) OR NOT(Q)
```

and

```
NOT(P OR Q)  =  NOT(P) AND NOT(Q)
```

Your expression `NOT(balance < 1000 AND salary >= 50000)` becomes

```
balance >= 1000 OR salary < 50000
```

De Morgan's laws apply to Boolean algebra with a binary logic. If you have NULL values, things get more complicated. The way to go depends on the result you are expecting. A very useful function, in this respect, is the `COALESCE` function which returns the first non-null parameter passed to it.

```
COALESCE(balance, 0) >= 1000 OR COALESCE(salary, 0) < 50000
```